# Coordinate transformation in LAStools?

Tags: coordinate-system, lidar, las, lastools

LAStools program only limited to UTM platform for coordinate transformation
(`las2project`, `las2transform`).

Is there any other ways to transform coordinate for local projection in LAStools? For example RSO Malaysia.

Answer (score 6):

A library that can read LAS data and links with [proj.4](http://proj4.org) is the easiest way to project data and apply datum transformations. Both [libLAS](http://liblas.org) and [PDAL](http://pdal.io) support this linkage.

Assuming the RSO Malaysia coordinate system is 
http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3168/, the fastest way to get going might be to pull down the PDAL [Docker](http://docker.com) image ([PDAL docker tutorial](http://www.pdal.io/tutorial/docker.html)), and issue the PDAL [translate](http://www.pdal.io/apps.html#translate-command) command with it:

```
$ docker run -v /local/path/to/my/data:/data pdal/pdal pdal translate -i /data/myfile.las \
    -o /data/output.las reprojection --filters.reprojection.out_srs="EPSG:3168"
```

Answer (score 3):

About three months ago [LAStools](http://rapidlasso.com/LAStools) was updated to provide support for most EPSG codes to offer more ways to re-project with [las2las](http://lastools.org/download/las2las_README.txt). However, there are still two limitations: (1) the re-projection must use the same datum and (2) some of less common projections such as Hotine Oblique Mercator used by RSO Malaysia are not (yet) implemented. For those cases las2las from [libLAS](http://liblas.org) or [PDAL](http://pdal.io) as are your only (free) options.